# Cannot post form data to flask using fetch api

Tags: post, flask, python-requests

I have problem posting data to my Flask server. The example data post just fine when I am using Postman, but I cannot do it from the front end.

The form is dynamically generated and looks like this:

```html
<div class="container" id="form-wrapper">
  <form
    id="comment-form"
    method="POST"
    onsubmit="send_comment(event)"
    class="border p-4 mt-4 rounded"
  >
    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Register</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Comment</label>
      <textarea
        rows="3"
        class="form-control"
        id="comment"
        aria-describedby="name_help"
        name="comment"
      ></textarea>
      <input
        type="hidden"
        class="form-control"
        id="geom"
        name="geom"
        value="${coords25832[0]} ${coords25832[1]}"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn-sm btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is the function sending the data:

```js
function send_data(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  let data = new FormData();
  data.comment = document.querySelector("form #comment").value;
  data.geom = document.querySelector("form #geom").value;
}

// Example data
// data = {"comment":"sd","geom":"567398.6224792203 7027428.422090762"}
fetch(`${baseurl}/api/comment`, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: new Headers({
    //'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  }),
  body: data,
})
  .then(function (res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Request failure: ", error);
  });
```

Finally, my route. I am trying to get the posted data. I have removed the code to save to DB, etc, below. I am just trying to get the data on the server side. But it fails and I cannot see why. I am just trying to post JSON or form data but I cannot get it to work, I don't seem to be able to fetch the posted data. I'm not sure if the problem is the front end or backend.

```py
@mod.route('/comment', methods=['POST'])
def map_comment():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("I am a post")
        if request.form:
            print("I have form data")
            # print(request.form['kommentar'])
        if request.data:
            print("I have data")
        if request.json:
            print("I have json")
            # Do stuff with the data...
        else:
            print("fail")
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all your endpoint is missing return value:

```
from flask import jsonify

@mod.route('/comment', methods=['POST'])
def map_comment():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("I am a post")
        if request.form:
            print("I have form data")
            #print(request.form['kommentar'])
        if request.data:
            print("I have data")
        if request.json:
            print("I have json")
            # Do stuff with the data...
            return jsonify({"message": "OK"})
        else:
            print("fail")

        return jsonify({})
```

and POSTed data should be formatted as JSON so that Flask can successfully parse it.

```
{
    method: "POST",
    headers: new Headers({
        //'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }),
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
```

Server was raising an exception when accessing `request.json` because of the wrong json format.

Comment: I had a return value later in my route but did not show add it to the post. formatting my data as JSON as you suggested worked however! 
The data sent to the server appar to be sent back as bytes?
b'{"comment":"test","geom":"567398.6224792203 7027428.422090762"}'
Is that right. I was expecting to capture it in the request.json statement? Do i really have to convert bytes back to string? Does not seem to be right

Comment: Use `request.get_json()` if you want a dict.

Comment: get_json worked fine. Thank you!
What i am baffled about is that is work fine using postman, posting the the json object by fetch API and it doe not work, get_json() return None.